# Understanding how lambda expression works

Tags: c#, lambda

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9,-_ ]{2,12}$");
            return panel1.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>()
.Select(uc => uc.comboBox2).Any(cb => cb.Text == String.Empty);
```

as the code is for validation I am implementing this but I don't know how it works and where it flows. Can anyone help me to understand this line ?

```
return panel1.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>()
.Select(uc => uc.comboBox2).Any(cb => cb.Text == String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`panel1` - the control on your form
`.controls` - the list of controls added to `panel1`
`.OfType<UserControl1>()` - only controls that are of type `UserControl1`
`.Select(uc => uc.combobox2)` - the `combobox2` property (of each `UserControl1` (in `panel1`))
`.Any(cb => cb.Text == String.Empty)` - evaluates to true if any of those comboxbox's `Text` property is an empty string.

So basically if any of the `Text` property of the `combobox2` property of the `UserControl1`'s added to your `panel1` control is empty, then return `true`, otherwise `false`.

---

Some explanation about `.Select(uc => uc.comboxbox2)`.

This is saying call each item in the collection `uc`. For each `uc` return the value created on the right of the `=>`. In that case it's `uc.combobox2`. Imagine doing that to a single one, well you'd get a variable of type `ComboBox` (i'd guess). Because this is in the context of the `Select` method, we will do that for each item. Doing it for all of them means you get a collection of them, based on your collection of `UserControl1`'s.

Regarding `.Any(cb => cb.Text == String.Empty)`
The parameter to the `Any` method is the same thing as above, however it might be confusing as the part "on the right of the `=>`" is in this case something that evaluates to `true` or `false`. The `Any` method expects something that transforms each item in a collection (a `ComboBox` in this case) into a true or false. It will then return true if any of those transform into `true`, and if not then it'll return `false`.

Comment: What does the `uc => uc.combobox2` part do? That is what the OP is asking.

Comment: Missed the comment. Edited.

Comment: thank you sir but can you exagerate what does this means
uc => uc.combobox2 and how it works here are two things which i dont understand cb => cb.Text == String.Empty this

Comment: Nice explanation of the lambda expression.

Comment: Nice answer George, I was going to go into detail but I saw your edit so I stopped.  Great answer.

Comment: @aquibRocks Check my answer, maybe it can give you further hints about your question :)

Answer (score 5):

- `.Select(...)` iterates all items in a given collection and projects a new collection as `IEnumerable<T>` where the item is the selected property or any object.
- `.Any(...)` iterates all items in the projected collection and checks if at least one item satisfy a boolean condition.

#### Update:

Both `Select(...)` and `Any(...)` have a lambda expression as input parameters. In C#:

```
uc => uc.comboBox2
```

... is equivalent to (there're other variations):

```
delegate(UserControl1 uc) { return uc.comboBox2; }
```

... and:

```
cb => cb.Text == String.Empty
```

... is equivalent to:

```
delegate(ComboBox cb) { return cb.Text == String.Empty }
```

In fact, excepting expression trees, lambda expressions are just delegates with a more functional programming syntax.

#### Deferred execution

As a side-note, there's an important point in your code: `Select` does not execute (lists, collections: anything implementing `IEnumerable<T>`) until it's iterated. That is, performing a `foreach`, calling `.ToList()`/`.ToArray()` or your case: `.Any(...)`.

This is important, because the objects being part of a deferred execution may have an invalid state when the whole enumerable is *enumerated*.

I'm going to give you a good example using your code:

```
// First of all we select the combo boxes identifiers:
var selectedItems = panel1.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>()
.Select(uc => uc.comboBox2.ID);

// Then we get the first combobox and we change its identifier:
var firstCombo = panel1.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>().First().comboBox2;
firstCombo.comboBox2.ID = "ChangedID";

// Now we convert the selectedItems to a list with ToList():
List<string> list = selectedItems.ToList();
```

Will the first item of the list of combo boxes IDs have the first combo box with the original ID or the changed one? The answer is: it'll be the changed one, since `Select(...)` was executed when the `ToList()` was invoked!

Comment: When you write the old-fashioned anonymous method with the `delegate` keyword, you cannot leave out the type of the parameters (unless you omit the parameters entirely which is not possible in this case because you _use_ the parameters in the body). So you must write `delegate(UserControl1 uc) { return uc.comboBox2; }` and `delegate(ComboBox cb) { return cb.Text == String.Empty; }`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, thank you for your correction. I was @ work and I had to extend my answer in a few time.

Comment: This is overall a good answer, but there is a miss-statement.  Lambda expressions only exist as c# syntax (to generate anonymous methods or expression trees).  There are no .net methods that accept "lambda expressions" as parameters.

Comment: @DavidB I believe my statement "In .NET and C# [...]" tries to say that: I'm not talking about how it's compiled. BTW, I can clarify it more.

Answer (score 4):

A lambda has three parts.  An Arrow  "  =>  ", parameters to the left of the arrow and an expression or a block to the right of the arrow.

You are using these lambdas to create anonymous methods.  Lambdas can also be used to create expression trees, but I won't go into that here.

This method call to [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) projects each input into an output:

```
//use the expression syntax, which implies that the value of the expression is returned.
// creates an anonymous method.
Select(uc => uc.comboBox2)
```

This is done by the expression of the lambda, which accesses and returns the combobox2 property's value of the input.  This code does the same thing:

```
//use the block syntax to create an anonymous method.
Select(uc => { return uc.comboBox2; })
```

If you don't like the lambda, you can use a method you define as long as the signature of the method matches the parameter of the method you are calling.

```
//define a method yourself.
public ComboBox GetComboBox(UserControl1 uc)
{
  return uc.combobox2;
}

//use that method in the Select call.
Select(GetComboBox)
```

---

This method call to [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) enumerates the source and stops when the first item matching the criteria is found, returning true.  If the end is reached without finding a matching item, `Any` returns false.

```
 Any(cb => cb.Text == String.Empty);
```

The lambda expression generates an anonymous method that returns a bool.  Any uses that method to check Comboboxes.  Each combobox is checked until one returns true - then true is returned by `Any`.  If no comboboxes return true, then false is returned by `Any`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever used Power Shell?  The reason I bring that up is essentially the Lambda Expression is *usually piping data*. This method of piping the data allows the usage of Linq to be significantly faster and more efficient. Which allows faster ease with certain query syntax.

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that you can use to
>   create delegates or expression tree types. By using lambda
>   expressions, you can write local functions that can be passed as
>   arguments or returned as the value of function calls. Lambda
>   expressions are particularly helpful for writing LINQ query
>   expressions.
>
> To create a lambda expression, you specify input parameters (if any)
>   on the left side of the lambda operator =>, and you put the expression
>   or statement block on the other side. For example, the lambda
>   expression x => x * x specifies a parameter that’s named x and returns
>   the value of x squared. You can assign this expression to a delegate
>   type, as the following example shows:

```
delegate int del(int i);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    del myDelegate = x => x * x;
    int j = myDelegate(5); //j = 25
}
```

The thing to note about Lambda Expressions is the `=>` Operator.  It has the same precedence as an assignment of `=` and is a right associative.

The Microsoft Developer Network has a lot on Lambda as it is very [important](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). Another great resource for Lambda Expressions is the *C# 5.0 In A Nutshell by O'Reily*.

In your case the Lambda is stating: If any of your user control fields are null, then return true.  Otherwise it will return false. It is a efficient way to use the Regular Expressions and Lambda Expressions to error check the field.

Also @George Duckett goes into more specific details on your codes meaning.